# Entering HTML form data in PHP code?

Tags: php, html, redirect

There is a textbox (`name="url"`) in a form which contains a page URL. When the form is submitted, data will be sent to a PHP page. I want to know how to redirect that PHP page to the URL from the form? I have the code for redirection:

```
header( 'Location: www.google.com' );
```

Now I want to know how use that URL from the form, like so:

```
header( 'Location: << here should be the url we got from form >>' );
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
header("Location: {$_POST['url']}\r\n");
```

? Edit: Sorry for the really late response, should have checked.

**Edit 2:** If you want to redirect after twenty seconds, add this in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20; <?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>" />
```

And make sure to include a link back to the page somewhere in your body for accessibility:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">Go back</a>
```

Comment: thanks it works minitech.....but can we set it to run after some seconds ? redirect after 20 seconds like that ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use string concatenation...

```
header('Location: ' . $_POST['url']);
exit;
```

I am pretty sure `header()` doesn't allow `\n` or anything that would allow additional headers to be set. *If* it did, it would be [HTTP splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_%28OWASP-DV-016%29#HTTP_Splitting), and that is bad.

Also, make sure you `exit`. User agents can ignore your `Location` header if they want. The WayBackMachine bot also has a [habit of ignoring `Location` headers](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx).

This does violate some recommendation (can't remember which right now) though that says user input should not be placed in a `Location` header. But so long as you don't allow `\n`, you should be OK. :)

Comment: wow thanks it works...but can we set it to run after some seconds ? redirect after 20 seconds like that ?

Comment: @Navi You'd need to use some HTML in your `head` element I think. I'm not sure if it works as a header (despite the HTML saying `http-equiv`).

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: '.$_POST['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply concatenate the value passed by the post with the location string to redirect? Or am I not understanding the problem correctly?